# 403 error when attempting to fetch google analytics 4 data from app script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-api, google-oauth, google-analytics-4, google-analytics-data-api

I am attempting to connect a custom community connector to google analytics 4 in order to get data from analytics and be able to modify it in app script and then send it to data studio. However I am having difficulty connecting and retrieving data from google analytics.

The error:

```
    { error: 
   { code: 403,
     message: 'Google Analytics Data API has not been used in project 640397821842 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsdata.googleapis.com/overview?project=640397821842 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.',
     status: 'PERMISSION_DENIED',
     details: [ [Object], [Object] ] } }
```

I have the scopes set up

```
 "oauthScopes": [
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/script.external_request",
    "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.readonly"
  ],
```

The code i am trying to test:

```
function testFetch(){
  const options = {
  entry: { propertyId: 263290444},
  "dateRanges": [{ "startDate": "2020-12-01", "endDate": "2021-03-01" }],
  "dimensions": [{ "name": "country" }],
  "metrics": [{ "name": "activeUsers" }],
  // etc.
  }
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(
    'https://analyticsdata.googleapis.com/v1alpha:runReport', {
    method: 'POST',
    muteHttpExceptions: true,
    headers: {
      Authorization : `Bearer ${ScriptApp.getOAuthToken()}`
    },
    contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
    payload: JSON.stringify(options)
  });
  var result = JSON.parse(response.getContentText());
  console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For those with the same issue who may have overlooked some steps:

1. Create an API project at https://console.cloud.google.com/
2. Make sure to connect your appscript project to your cloud API project by changing the Google Cloud Platform (GCP) Project in appscript settings (It is set to a default project when you start).
3. Enable the required APIs from the API Library in the cloud project.
4. Now you will be able to fetchurls related to the APIs you have enabled.

Answer (score 2):

> 'Google Analytics Data API has not been used in project 640397821842 before or it is disabled. Enable it by visiting https://console.developers.google.com/apis/api/analyticsdata.googleapis.com/overview?project=640397821842 then retry. If you enabled this API recently, wait a few minutes for the action to propagate to our systems and retry.',
> status:

The problem you are having is that you have not enabled the API in Google developer console  You need to follow the link in the error message then go to library and look for Google analytics data api and enable it.

Once you have enabled it try and run your application again.

[image]

Comment: @DalmTo Thank you for the response. The project # is the same regardless of propertyid put and it leads to an error that says i do not have permissions. that being said I have tried enabling the api in the developer console, adding a developer email to the account in analytics and using an api key, none of which has changed the error.

Comment: This is not a permissions issue this is a set up issue you have not **enabled** the API in Google developer console. for the client id and client secret you are currently using.  Check this video https://youtu.be/pBVAyU4pZOU?t=179 only search for Google Analytics Data api

Comment: @DalmTo My project was not in fact connected to the API (i completely overlooked that).